# running external program via PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, pdf2swf

I need an expert's help.
I need to execute a program via php script. It works well on Windows, but not on Linux.
The command is also OK in shell but won't run via php it can't run. Also php can run the Linux commands, but I need to run another program `pdf2swf`.
please help me to solve this.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $_REQUEST["n_o_p"]; $i++) { 
  $oExec = exec($_SESSION['path']."pdf2swf -p ".$i."-".$i." ".$_SESSION['path']."upload/".$_SESSION['f_n']." -o ".$_SESSION['path'].$tmp_dir."/data/pages/document".$i.".swf");
}
```

Comment: what code are you using?

Comment: Um.  If you're trying to run pdf2swf.exe on linux, you're really just going to be SOL.  You'll need to find a Linux executable to do that.

From there, you'll just need to exec you linux command pretty much like you have your existing call.

Comment: @Amir please edit the question and not post it as comment

Comment: @Amir the last code you pasted has an unclosed exec. I put the first one inline so you can edit it there.

Comment: for($i=0 ; $i<= $_REQUEST["n_o_p"];$i++){ $oExec = exec($_SESSION['path']."pdf2swf -p ".$i."-".$i." ".$_SESSION['path']."upload/".$_SESSION['f_n']." -o ".$_SESSION['path'].$tmp_dir."/data/pages/document".$i.".swf";} this the code, thank you for answers

Comment: as I said on me question I copied this and pasted on shell and it worked correctly, but it can't run from php code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php shell_exec('command'); ?>
```

Comment: these command can run Linux shell commands well but for third party programs I couldn't use